# SQLite: How to get table values that match the current month?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite table that has one column for an amount of money spent, and one column for when (YYYY-MM-DD) that money was spent. Both columns are strings. How do I write a query that will give me the total amount that was spent this month?

The closest I've come is

```
select sum(expenseValue)
from expenses_table
where CAST(substr(date,6,2) AS INT) == strftime('%m', 'now ')
```

which is not an error but also does not produce any value.

Comment: you `date` column datatype is `varchar` or `datetime`?.. you are not suppose to use sqlite keywords as column name ie `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do the comparison as integers, do the comparison as strings:

```
select sum(expenseValue)
from expenses_table
where substr(date, 6, 2) = strftime('%m', 'now')
```

What might be happening is that "6" (as an integer) is not equal to "06" as a string.

Comment: Hmm, there is still not any value being returned.

select sum(expenseValue)
from expenses_table
where substr(date, 6, 2) = '06'

will work, but the comparison against the strftime does not.

Comment: @callynx . . . I just noticed that you have a space after "now".  Perhaps that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your date is in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`, you could use date modifiers to do calculations on dates easily:

```
SELECT * FROM expense WHERE date > date('now', 'start of month');
```

In general, you can issue simple queries as such:

```
SELECT * FROM expense WHERE date > '2016-07-01';
```

See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0):

Apparently strftime('%m%', 'now') returns 07 even though the current month is June. So the correct query for the current month is 
select sum(expenseValue)
from expenses_table
where substr(date, 6, 2) =  strftime('%m','now', '-1 month'). 
Thanks anyway to Gordon!